# strace 'open' calls in a library of an executable

Tags: linux, unix, execution, trace, strace

I have a program with no source code.

When I run it, I have a "Can't open file..." error in the logs.

I called **strace** to trace the *open* calls on the kernel, in that way:

```
strace -e trace=open,close,read,write,connect,accept your-command-here
```

However, it seems there is none of the *open* calls I am expecting (that shall happen before that the log says "Can't open file...")

The executable indeed delegated the *open* call to a tierce library.
It  seems that **strace** only trace the calls from the executable on the kernel, not those of the libraries depencies.

I tried to use **ltrace** to trace what happens in the subsequent libraries, but it doesnt display the same informations as **strace**, only the function calls (which are not human-readable).

Is there a way to run **strace** on the executable and the libraires in the same time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strace` should be showing all of the `open` calls.  However:

- Perhaps your application calls a subprocess to do work.  For that case, you can add a `-f` option.
- On the other hand, it may be doing the work by opening a socket (or similar) connection to another process.  For that case, you will not see any trace.  Likewise, if you are using the [syslog](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog.html) interface, then the actual work may be done outside your process, potentially in the kernel where you cannot trace with this tool.

Comment: the '-f' option works perfectly ! 
Thanks Thomas for your help

Comment: I had a similar issue. Not only I had to use `-f`, but also include `openat` in the list of calls to trace. Apparently, `openat` is "new" glibc 2.10 (published in 2009-05-09).